# Ways to restrict Azure Website / WebApp to only be view-able internally on a vnet

Tags: azure, cloud, firewall, azure-web-app-service, internal

So heres the two approaches I noticed. Is there any other way that I am missing and is there a favored approach? Pretty much I have a webAPI that i want to run as a webAPP and I am trying to figure out the best way to keep it internal only

One way that seems somewhat involved is the following

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

the second way I noticed is the following

http://www.microsofttrends.com/2014/09/30/add-a-firewall-to-your-microsoft-azure-web-site/

The latter looks quicker I am just wondering if there's a preferred way to go about this or a newer more standard way to do this?

**update**

> As of 7/23/2015 this is not possible but the closest solution is the accepted answer. One would have to whitelist all of the public IP addresses inside of their vnets. The reason you cant specify the range of addresses in the Azure vnet is because azure websites currently run on the public internet and they have no concept of the vnet ranges. Thus they cannot see the private ip address ranges that vnets create so you cant specify them in the web.config. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/introducing-app-service-environment/ may solve this in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple ip security rule in web.config?

```
<system.webServer>   
  <security> 
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound"> 
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="192.168.1.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/> 
    </ipSecurity> 
  </security>    
</system.webServer>
```

Just replace ipAddress and subnetMask to your VNet setup. You may also need to connect your web app to vnet first.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

Comment: By vnet setup you mean the gateway of the vnet or some other addy ? Mind you I didn't fully read that link yet

Comment: The entire VNet address space you chose for your VMs.

Comment: right now you have to whitelist each public IP in your vnet. You cannot whitelist the entire address space of your vnet because the azure website is running externally on the public vnet and unless your living in side of the vnet the azure website living on the public internet has no concept of that vnets address space (ie it wont see those private ip addresses assigned from the vnet only the public Ip addresses).  http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/introducing-app-service-environment/ may solve it in the future